How do I sort an object array based on a single member variable?
I have a Student class. It has a member variable score. I have an array students. I want to sort that array based on the score.
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

class Student
{
public:
    int score;

    //other stuff

    void construct(std::ifstream& _f)
    {
        _f >> score;
        //does other initialising as well
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inf("input.in")
    inf >> m;
    Student* students = new Student[MAX_M]; //creates the array
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        students[i].construct(inf); //inf is the inpout file
    }
    inf.close();

    //Here I want to sort the array based on the score variable :)
}


I tried using a lambda function with std::sort() but I think I did not inmpliment it correctly.

You should have added the lambda you tried that didn't work, it was probably a simple fix.

This post might help: How to sort with a lambda?.

See the solutions given in Sorting a vector of custom objects. That should be informational.

In ascending order of score:
std::sort(students, students + m, [](const Student & lhs, const Student & rhs) {
    return lhs.score < rhs.score;
});

In descending order of score:
std::sort(students, students + m, [](const Student & lhs, const Student & rhs) {
    return lhs.score > rhs.score;
});


First learn a bit more C++, you are still using new/delete which is not recommended (you already leak memory). For collections of students use std::vector.
A lambda can be used, but you can also use normal functions as predicates.
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct student_t
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    int score;
};

auto order_by_name(const student_t& lhs, const student_t& rhs)
{
    return lhs.name < rhs.name;
}

auto order_by_age(const student_t& lhs, const student_t& rhs)
{
    return lhs.age < rhs.age;
}

auto order_by_score(const student_t& lhs, const student_t& rhs)
{
    return lhs.score < rhs.score;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const student_t& student)
{
    os << "Student, name = " << student.name << ", age = " << student.age << ", score = " << student.score;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<student_t> students
    {
        {"alice",22,8},
        {"bob", 18, 6 },
        {"charlie", 33, 9 }
    };

    std::sort(students.begin(),students.end(), order_by_age);

    for(const auto& student : students)
    {
        std::cout << student << "\n";
    }
}

